# Numba - Shared memory in CUDA kernel not updating correctly

Tags: python, cuda, numba

Consider the following kernel, which counts the number of elements in `x` which are less than or equal to the corresponding element in `y`.

```
@cuda.jit
def count_leq(x, y, out):
    i = cuda.grid(1)
    shared = cuda.shared.array(1, dtype=DTYPE)
    if i < len(x):
        shared[0] += x[i] <= y[i]
    cuda.syncthreads()
    out[0] = shared[0]
```

However, the increments from each thread are not being saved properly in the shared array.

```
a = cuda.to_device(np.arange(5))  # [0 1 2 3 4]
b = cuda.to_device(np.arange(5))  # [0 1 2 3 4]
out = cuda.to_device(np.zeros(1)) # [0]
count_leq[1,len(a)](a, b, out)
print(out[0])                     # 1.0, but should be 5.0
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm confused because `cuda.shared.array` is shared by all threads in a given block, right? How do I accumulate the increments using the same 1-element array?

I also tried the following, which failed with the same behavior as the above version.

```
@cuda.jit
def count_leq(x, y, out):
    i = cuda.grid(1)
    if i < len(x):
        out[0] += x[i] <= y[i]
```

Comment: I suspect the issue is that you're updating (i.e., reading and immediately writing) the same cell of `shared` from all threads at the same time. I'd try try separating the writing (e.g., allocating `shared` to have the same shape as `x` and writing to `shared[i]` and, after the syncthreads, summing all elements in `shared`.

Comment: I would prefer using a 1-element `shared` array so that we can avoid the additional second loop. Is this possible?

Comment: Wait for a second person confirming this, as I am not super familiar with numba, but from what I remember of CUDA programming, what is happening is that all threads (running at the same time on parallel data) read the 0 value in `shared[0]` at the same time, so they all write 1 back (and overwrite eachother's value). The second loop and the separate output variables are necessary to ensure the count is correct

Comment: I could see that being a problem if I were assigning, but I'm incrementing with `+=` so I thought the behavior you described wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: That's the part where I am not sure. `+=` is R/W, but I don't know if numba has some mechanisms to make this an atomic operation. Given the result of your code, however, I would think that's not the case. Still, if it is an atomic operation, I think it would still be slower to synchronize all the threads so they read and write in a consistent way, rather than looping twice.

Comment: @AisforAmbition See [this](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) (although it is not up to date and does not fully match with your case).

Comment: There is [this](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cuda/reduction.html) functionality in Numba, but the documentation seems horrible if you want to coda a kernel that fuses reduction with something more complicated.

While in an ideal world everyone who starts doing parallel programming would know the basic primitives like "reduction", I fear we are not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **perform an atomic add operation explicitly**:

```py
@cuda.jit
def count_leq(x, y, out):
    i = cuda.grid(1)
    if i < len(x):
        cuda.atomic.add(out, 0, x[i] <= y[i])
```

Atomic adds are optimized on relatively new devices using for example an hardware warp reduction, but the operation tends not to scale when a large number of streaming-multiprocessors perform an atomic operations.

One solution to increase the performance of this kernel is to perform a block reduction of many values assuming the array is large enough. In practice, each thread can sum multiple items and perform one atomic operation in the end. The code should look like this (untested):

```py
# Must be launched with different parameters since 
# each threads works on more array items.
# The number of block should be 16 times smaller.
@cuda.jit
def count_leq(x, y, out):
    tid = cuda.threadIdx.x
    bid = cuda.blockIdx.x
    bdim = cuda.blockDim.x
    i = (bid * bdim * 16) + tid

    s = 0

    # Fast general case (far from the end of the arrays)
    if i+16*bdim < len(x):
        # Thread-local reduction
        # This loop should be unrolled
        for j in range(16):
            idx = i + j * bdim
            s += x[idx] <= y[idx]

    # Slower corner case (close to end of the arrays: checks are needed)
    else:
        for j in range(16):
            idx = i + j * bdim
            if idx < len(x):
                s += x[idx] <= y[idx]

    cuda.atomic.add(out, 0, s)
```

Note that 16 is an arbitrary value. It is certainly faster to use a bigger value like 64 for huge array and a smaller value for relatively small arrays.